# Limit Access Using WCF Data Services

Tags: .net, wcf, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I've been checking out **WCF Data Services** today and it looks great - but so far I haven't been able to find much about security -- specifically, limiting access to the services based on the connecting account.

In SQL you have some accounts that have read only access (and those are sometimes limited to a few tables) but so far in WCF Data Services I haven't found anything that.

I'm trying to find recommendations for limiting functionality (read, write access) and visibility (limit 'tables' they have access to)

Any recommendations on where to start -- Or do I need to start rolling my own? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word: [query interceptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842%28VS.100%29.aspx)! :-) Check them out.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little easier to implement but this is what I needed - Thanks a lot!